# Python Exe made with Pyinstaller is trying to find dll from wrong location

Tags: python, dll, exe, executable, pyinstaller

I have a onefile executable I made with pyinstaller on a 32-bit computer. I made sure to include the necessary dll files in the binaries section of my spec file. I verified that those files are being included using the archive viewer.

However, when I try running the exe file on a 64-bit computer that has Python already installed, it tries to find the dll files in the Python27/Scripts folder, which are not compatible with the other 32-bit dll already included in the exe file.

How do I include the 32-bit dll in my exe file and have 64-bit computers access it when the exe runs?

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code seems to set a rather high priority on the path searched through when loading DLLs. You can put it at the very beginning of your entry point into your programme.

```
try:
    import win32api
    win32api.SetDllDirectory(sys._MEIPASS)
except:
    pass
```